# How can I find faction leaders in Tropico 5?

Tags: tropico-5

I'm at the beginning of the game and have created an inquisition. It says that the inquisition can find faction leaders. But there's no option anywhere like that.

I have used the inquisition to "suppress" the royalist faction (without seeing any major changes in their numbers) after enabling that setting.

Now I'm supposed to find the royalist faction leader and kill/banish/bribe him. But I've gone through the Almanac > People> Scroll down to Special > ---- here it only shows revolutionary leader--- . But the royalist leader isn't identified.

So I tried opening the Almanac > Politics > Royalists > (50+ names). I tried clicking on each of those names one by one hoping that this might identify the faction leader. But it didn't. How do I identify him?